# ogr2ogr error: "Unable to initialize connection to the server ...."

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, ogr2ogr, mysql-spatial

I am getting the error detailed in the screenshot below when running ogr2ogr. The command used worked on my other computer. I am wondering if this is an error that is triggering because I do not have proper permissions.

[image: OGR2OGR error connecting to databes]

One last detail: the database I am uploading to exists.

Comment: Ideally just post the complete error message as text. Images are hard to read.

Comment: You've also tagged SQL Server and MySQL-Spatial, surely you are only using one of them?

Comment: Did you try specifying the driver, like the error suggests?

Comment: You say that the `Sinkin_Sandbox` database already exists, but does it exist on the server you're connecting to, `pdc-sql1`? Is it on a named instance that requires the name in the connection string, such as `pdc-sql1\FooInstance`?

Comment: yes the database exists on pdc-sql1. There is a system username and password that is used when I connect to the server. Do I need to add that to the command? If so, how would i change the command?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error and did the following until it worked.

1. Mine was a fresh developer version installation on a new laptop.  I needed to `enable TCP/IP` connection with `SQL Server Configuration Manager`
2. Check I can `telnet localhost 1433`.  If screen goes blank it means you connected and it's working.
3. I'd also idiotically got the `SA` password wrong.  It was still telling me that it could not `create the database` although it was just wrong password.  I logged into SQL server with `Windows Authentication` and reset the `SA` password to the one I was using the connection string.
4. My command was:

   ogr2ogr -overwrite -progress -f MSSQLSpatial -s_srs epsg:27700 -t_srs epsg:4326 "MSSQL:driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=localhost;timeout=0;Database=importer;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx" opname_gb.gpkg -FieldTypeToString All -nln opname_gb